# Is $g$ the unique function with this property?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove/Disprove: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f : A \to B$ be a function. If there is a
function $g : B \to A$ such that $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$, then $g$  is the unique function with this property.

I'm confused. Would $f^{-1}$  be another function? Or is this problem saying $g= f^{-1}$?

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

$A=\{3,7\}$,

$B=\{3,7,9001\}$

and $f$ defined by

$f(3):=3$

$f(7):=7$.

As long as $g$ maps $3$ back to $3$ and $7$ back to $7$, the function $g\circ f$ will be the identity on $A$, while there are two options to where $g$ may map $9001$ to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c\}$. Define $f: A \to B$ by $$f(1) = a, f(2) = b.$$ Define $g_1,g_2: B \to A$ by
$$g_1(a) = 1, \;  g_1(b) = 2, \;g_1(c) = 1$$
and
$$ g_2(a) = 1, \; g_2(b) = g_2(c) = 2.$$
Then, $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f$ but $g_1 \neq g_2$.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the problem is asking you to prove that if $f^{-1}$ (f inverse) exists, then that inverse is unique.

Say there are two such functions, $g_1 : B \mapsto A$ and $g_2 : B \mapsto A$
such that $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f = \text{id}\, A$. Then we need to show that $g_1$ is the same function as $g_2$, that is, for all $b \in B$, $g_1(b) = g_2(b)$.

You can easily show this if $f$ is surjective, since for every $B \in B$ there is some $a \in A : f(a) = b$ and then we have $g_1(b) = a$ and $g_2(b) = a$.

But if $f$ is not surjective, the proposition does not hold.

Comment: Two-sided inverses are unique; $g$ is not a two-sided inverse in the question.

Comment: Yes, the point of my last line is that since nobody said in the proposition that every element of $B$ can be obtained by mapping some element of $A$, the proposition was not true.

Comment: Nonetheless, your interpretation of the question in the first line of your answer is *wrong* and hence you don't answer the question at all. Moreover, your answer may confuse the asker, because you may make them think that a left inverse is the same as a two-sided inverse, while this is obviously false. Unless, as you said, there already is right-inverse (assuming AC, being surjective is equivalent to having a right inverse).